# How can I catch AmqpConnectException under Spring AMQP framework?

Tags: spring, exception, rabbitmq, amqp

When I stop the rabbitmq server, the exception below will be thrown:

```
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:62) ~[spring-rabbit-1.6.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:306) ~[spring-rabbit-1.6.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:547) ~[spring-rabbit-1.6.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1411) ~[spring-rabbit-1.6.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1392) ~[spring-rabbit-1.6.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1368) ~[spring-rabbit-1.6.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(RabbitAdmin.java:336) ~[spring-rabbit-1.6.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.redeclareElementsIfNecessary(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1123) [spring-rabbit-1.6.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$800(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:98) [spring-rabbit-1.6.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1329) [spring-rabbit-1.6.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.FrameHandlerFactory.create(FrameHandlerFactory.java:47) ~[amqp-client-3.6.5.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:822) ~[amqp-client-3.6.5.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:778) ~[amqp-client-3.6.5.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:898) ~[amqp-client-3.6.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:297) ~[spring-rabbit-1.6.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 9 common frames omitted
```

How can I catch this exception?  Should I create or implement some handler?

Answer (score 3):

I Had the same problem. When I run my application without running rabbitmq server I had these endless error messages.
So, there are few solutions, depending on your needs.

1. If you try to avoid endless messaging about the same error, you can configure **RecoveryBackOff** strategy for **AbstractRabbitListenerContainerFactory**.

   ```
   SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
   int maxAttempts = 3;
   FixedBackOff recoveryBackOff = new FixedBackOff(DEFAULT_INTERVAL, maxAttempts);
   factory.setRecoveryBackOff(recoveryBackOff);
   ```

   Here, **maxAttemps** it's max number of attempts to reconnect. And first parameter is interval between two attempts (DEFAULT_INTERVAL = 5000ms).

So, in this case *SimpleMessageListenerContainer* will try to reconnect three more times and will calm down.

2. If you need to do something with these connection fails you cat implement spring **ApplicationListener** for **ListenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent** or even for more general - **AmqpEvent**  [as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43209271/6061701)

Answer (score 0):

I made this way:

```
@Configuration
@EnableRabbit
public class AmqpConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        ExponentialBackOff recoveryBackOff = new ExponentialBackOff();
        factory.setRecoveryBackOff(recoveryBackOff);
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Using the BackOffExponencial class, your server will check whether rabbitMq is online. This service will check in exponential time.

Exemple:

For 10 attempts the sequence will be as follows:

request # ... back off

1 ................. 2000

2 ................. 3000

3 ................. 4500

4 ................. 6750

5 ................. 10125

6 ................. 15187

7 ................. 22780

8 ................. 30000

9 ................. 30000

10 ................. 30000